# Reading a variable from another JSP file

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, scope

In **one.jsp**, I have

```
<% int testVar1 = 1; %>
```

In **two.jsp**, I have

```
<%@ include file="one.jsp" %>
<% if(testVar1 == 1) { %>
<!-- Should equal 1 -->
<% } else { %>
<!-- Does not equal 1 -->
<% } %>
```

However, the correct conditional path is not always taken. If I do not read testVar1 before the conditional test is performed, it always evaluates as true even if testVar1 was set to 0 in **one.jsp**.

Is this the correct way to read a variable from a second JSP file?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. "even if testVar1 was set to 0 in one.jsp": it's set to 1, not to 0. And what do you mean by "if I do not read testVar1"?

Comment: If you want to reduce the complexity of the JSP, follow best practices and move the Java out of the JSP and into Java classes (using beans, custom tags etc).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see any mistake in the code, it should work as intended.

As for reading `testVar1` before or after the conditional test is performed, should not make any difference.

What I think may be the issue is your JSPs may not be updating properly, i.e. if you update `one.jsp` to make `testVar1 = 0` it may not necessarily reflect since it is an included JSP in `two.jsp`, so you would also need to update `two.jsp` so that when the `two.jsp` is compiled it takes the updated `one.jsp` during compilation. So in short update both JSPs if you make any changes.

**Note:** Please also consider what @Lion says in his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11620231/reading-a-variable-from-another-jsp-file#comment15387513_11620231). It would help in future development.

Hope this helps.

Comment: You were correct in assuming it was an updating issue. Thank you for your help, and I will be sure to take @Lion's advice in the future.